# Local SQL Server: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-express

This problem has appeared on my PC a few days ago, without any changes I have made to the Visual Studio/SQL Server settings.

When trying to perform any manual operation on the database file (*.mdf) in Visual Studio, I get the following error:

> The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)

(For example, when trying to create a new table, or when showing an existing table's data)

How I can fix this error?

Comment: Please confirm which version of SQL Server Express you are using - 2005, 2008, 2008R2, 2012 etc.  Also you have said it's your local database but please confirm what level of permission you have to the DB on the credentials you are using?

Comment: My version is 2008R2. About the level of permission, I'm not sure how do I determine that. However, it doesn't seem to be the problem - I get the same error, even on a brand new project...

Comment: What version of windows are you running and did you install a service pack recently?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you or someone else has not changed your rights on master. In order to add anything a record is added to that table.

*Addendum:*
You can run the following script to determine who has what permissions and whether they are implicit or explicit.

```
WITH perms_cte as
(
    select USER_NAME(p.grantee_principal_id) AS principal_name,
            dp.principal_id,
            dp.type_desc AS principal_type_desc,
            p.class_desc,
            OBJECT_NAME(p.major_id) AS object_name,
            p.permission_name,
            p.state_desc AS permission_state_desc
    from    sys.database_permissions p
    inner   JOIN sys.database_principals dp
    on     p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
)
--users
SELECT p.principal_name,  p.principal_type_desc, p.class_desc, p.[object_name], p.permission_name, p.permission_state_desc, cast(NULL as sysname) as role_name
FROM    perms_cte p
WHERE   principal_type_desc <> 'DATABASE_ROLE'
UNION
--role members
SELECT rm.member_principal_name, rm.principal_type_desc, p.class_desc, p.object_name, p.permission_name, p.permission_state_desc,rm.role_name
FROM    perms_cte p
right outer JOIN (
  select role_principal_id, dp.type_desc as principal_type_desc, member_principal_id,user_name(member_principal_id) as member_principal_name,user_name(role_principal_id) as role_name--,*
from    sys.database_role_members rm
INNER   JOIN sys.database_principals dp
ON     rm.member_principal_id = dp.principal_id
) rm
ON     rm.role_principal_id = p.principal_id
order by 1
--- thanks to Jamie Thomson for this ditty
```

A more few suggestions;

Trace the call using profiler and confirm you are connecting as the user you think you are - sp_who2 might be another way to verify that.

Verify your process is in the correct database. Use the c# connection and run SELECT DB_NAME() - write the result somewhere you can read to confirm.

If this works from one environment but not another I would strongly suspect the connection string.

Check that you do not have authentication errors reported in your SQL logs. These again would indicate possible connection issues.

Comment: I don't think I've changed anything. How can I assure this?

Comment: I added some code to the post. Execute a "USE master" and run the script.

Comment: A summary that might help at least point you in the right direction is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The conventional wisdom on this error is that it likely reflects a lost or corrupted DLL (in either SQL Server or Visual Studio).  And the SOP is to reinstall, though it seems that that does not always work either.

Comment: The problem is in VS itself, as when running the project, the database operates successfully. I have reinstalled VS and the problem is still here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Visual Studio as administrator

Right click Visual Studio --> Run as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to the database in SQL Server Management Studio.  That'll at least narrow down whether it's a database permission issue or something else.  Also, check to confirm that the database exists and you have permission to access it.  (Like Joe suggested.)

Assuming that checks out...  My googling found a guy with a very similar sounding problem.  He said that the runas administrator thing Adel suggested worked for him, but there were other issues that could also cause the error message, including VS not being able to find the IIS virtual server specified in the Web Application Project file (permissions? renamed?).  Confirm that the file exists and you have permission to access it.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/317124/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-in-webapplication-project